# What is a caret exactly

Tags: javascript, css

say you were to build a text editor without using the input element, which is what I am doing for learning purposes and I got to the part where I need to show a caret and I figured out that I don't know what a caret is exactly.

- is it an html element on its own?
- is it just a pure css effect?
- is it just a dummy character that have an actual index in a string?

I tried to explore the `shadow dom` of the default `input` element but there was no mention of the caret, any ideas what is exactly?

I have built the logic to the caret and its position and got to the part where I need to display it

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: It's a conceptual thing which exists in text editors, however it does not exist in any way, shape or form in HTML/DOM/CSS/JS. So it's up to you how you fake implement it.

Comment: This will help - https://ctrlq.org/code/20086-css-arrow-caret-symbol

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl thanks a lot, that's was what I needed just was unsure if it should be an element, feel free to add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A caret is an graphic placed by the UI to indicate where the current text insertion point is located.  See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)) that discusses it.

Typically a caret isn't a graphical design element, but is managed by the system underlying it.  Only some input elements use a caret, specifically those that allow text input by the user.  This is similar and closely related to the way that some UIs will show the current input field by providing a highlight or coloring around the field.

Each input field maintains its own current insertion point, and the caret is displayed at the current insertion point for the currently selected edit field, only.  There's only ever one caret in a graphical system, and it's used as cue to the user of where typed characters would be placed.  The caret, properly placed, is often shown between characters, but may also be shown atop the current character, as well.

The user manipulates the caret position by doing any of a few actions:

- use the arrow keys to change the insertion point
- add or delete characters in the current input field
- switch to another input field (e.g. TAB to the next field)

The caret can usually be manipulated programmatically by these types of API calls to set insertion position, which typically requires an input field and an index to the insertion point.

The caret may be any shape defined by the system, or any shape that you choose to display.  Some carets include an animation, as well, such as blinking, cycling colors, or even bouncing.

Answer (score 1):

A caret is an ascii character or symbol ex: @.
It can be used in html to depict drop down or drop up. It's not a standalone tag on its own. Just for representational purposes. 
There's ▲ (▲) and ▼ (▼)

https://ctrlq.org/code/20086-css-arrow-caret-symbol

Answer (score 1):

Caret is a pointed arrow symbol (**in any direction**). You can manipulate it the way you want (like changing the width, color and so on).

For help, see [this site](https://ctrlq.org/code/20086-css-arrow-caret-symbol).